# Python - Indentation Error After Comment After Else Block

Tags: python, syntax

I have this code:

```
if k == 1:
    df02_MASTER = df02.copy()
    #df02_MASTER.drop(['ID'], inplace=True)
else:
    df02 = df09.copy()
# Reasonable assignment variable names; will be unique
var_names = ( \
    'asn_i' \
    + df02.index.get_level_values('ID').astype(str) \
    + '_Pos' \
    + df02.index.get_level_values('Position') \
).to_series(index=df02.index)
```

When I run this code (if/else block at beginning and all), I get an indentation error at the var_names = statement:

```
>>> if k == 1:
...     df02_MASTER = df02.copy()
...     #df02_MASTER.drop(['ID'], inplace=True)
... else:
...     df02 = df09.copy()
... # Reasonable assignment variable names; will be unique
... var_names = ( \
  File "<stdin>", line 7
    var_names = ( \
    ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>     'asn_i' \
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    'asn_i' \
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>     + df02.index.get_level_values('ID').astype(str) \
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    + df02.index.get_level_values('ID').astype(str) \
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>     + '_Pos' \
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    + '_Pos' \
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>     + df02.index.get_level_values('Position') \
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    + df02.index.get_level_values('Position') \
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> ).to_series(index=df02.index)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ).to_series(index=df02.index)
    ^
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

HOWEVER, when I run starting at the comment, no problems:

```
>>> # Reasonable assignment variable names; will be unique
>>> var_names = ( \
...     'asn_i' \
...     + df02.index.get_level_values('ID').astype(str) \
...     + '_Pos' \
...     + df02.index.get_level_values('Position') \
... ).to_series(index=df02.index)
>>>
```

It appears that Python does not recognize the unindented comment as unindented and therefore the end of the else block (at least that is my hypothesis).

**How does one end an else block explicitly when the next line that is unidented is a comment?**

Keep in mind that once I get this code running reliably, this will all be in another level for block. As a result, skipping a line is not an option as that will kick me out of the outer for block. Something like this:

```
l = 0
for k in range(1,(n+1)):
    l += 1
    print(k, dg, file002)
    if k == 1:
        df02_MASTER = df02.copy()
        #df02_MASTER.drop(['ID'], inplace=True)
    else:
        df02 = df09.copy()
    # Reasonable assignment variable names; will be unique
    var_names = ( \
        'asn_i' \
        + df02.index.get_level_values('ID').astype(str) \
        + '_Pos' \
        + df02.index.get_level_values('Position') \
    ).to_series(index=df02.index)
    df02.rename(columns={'Time' : 'Start'})
    yada
    yada
    yada
```

Comment: WHen you're typing in the REPL you need to enter a blank line at the end of a block, not just reduce the indentation.

Comment: Won't a blank line kick me out of the for block (see the very end of the post)?

Comment: I was talking about the `if` in the first code snippet. It's not inside `for`.

Comment: You only need the blank line when you're ending the outermost block.

Comment: In other words, you need it whenever your indentation goes back to the beginning of the line.

Comment: I don't follow you. How do I terminate the else block within the for loop?

Comment: By putting the next statement at the same indentation of `if` and `else`. But if you also want to end the `for` loop, you need a blank line.